# cucumber-scala and Play Framework integration testing

Tags: scala, selenium, playframework-2.0, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I've managed to get cucumber-scala up and running on a Play/Scala. Now I want to run the entire play application so that I can use something like Selenium to test my application.

My Current attempts have lead me to

```
 val app = new FakeApplication()
 val port = 3333

  lazy val browser: TestBrowser = TestBrowser.of(webDriverClass, Some("http://localhost:" + port))
  lazy val server = TestServer(port, app)
```

Of course this FakeApplication() is **not configured** in any way... Am I approaching this incorrectly? This application is also multi-module and Ideally I would like to have the feature tests run per module (see output from tree below)

```
├── README.md
├── build.sbt
├── conf
│   ├── application.conf
│   └── routes
├── logs
│   └── application.log
├── modules
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── app
│   │   ├── conf
│   │   ├── target
│   │   └── test
│   └── module2
│       ├── app
│       ├── conf
│       └── target
└── project
    ├── build.properties
    ├── plugins.sbt
    ├── project
    │   └── target
    └── target
        ├── config-classes
        ├── resolution-cache
        ├── scala-2.10
        └── streams
```

I am aware that Play has a selenium integration which can be used to drive my tests. However I have a business requirement for feature files, as they are used as a reporting mechanism. I am not absolutely tied to Cucumber so if anyone is aware of a way of driving browser based tests using Feature files that would also be acceptable to me?

Thanks,

Ben

Update:

I was running through IntelliJ, which causes a server to run with no routes or anything provided. I assume this is because it runs with a default blank application.

However When running through `sbt test` I get the following output:

Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

```
1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Router not found: admin.Routes]
  while locating play.api.inject.guice.FakeRouterProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
```

Comment: “I am having difficulties getting the application to start” – what problems are you seeing exactly, errors when you run the tests?  Can you show us your full code: where do you call `server.start()`, for example?

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec Sorry I should clarify. I can get the application to start however there are no routes or anything configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default configuration settings for `IntegrationTest` in sbt, and [ScalaTestPlusPlay](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest), here are the directories to use:

```
src/it/scala     – scala IT code
src/it/java      – java IT code
src/it/resources – resources, including configuration
```

Place your `application.conf` and `routes` files in the resources directory and **FakeApplication** will pick it up. You can also set the paths in your sbt script to some other place.

**If** all of your development/integration testing machines are Unix-like and you use git for VC, you can use a *relative symlink<sup>1</sup>* to your real routes file.

For Windows or other VCS's, you'll likely have to copy the routes file and do double maintenance.

*<sup>1</sup>* symlink using a relative path to the original, e.g., `../../../conf/routes`.

Comment: `ScalaTestPlusPlay` is probably not required, but it integrates ScalaTest's selenium support nicely with Play.